# English for 'cross the mark'

Tags: phrases, expressions

In my first language when we talk about some index rising or, for example, somebody climbing a mountain we often use the phrase that can be directly translated into English like 'crossed the mark (of 1 km above the sea)', meaning that the index or the person have reached certain level/altitude and is now above it. Is there a phrase in English that means the same thing and sounds natural?

Comment: You could try "passed a (or *the*) milestone."

Answer (score 6):

The same expression is used in English:

- [Covid-19 Cases In India Cross 1 Million Mark, Deaths 25,000](https://www.huffingtonpost.in/entry/covid-19-coronavirus-india-1-million_in_5f112874c5b6d14c336580e5)
- [Trudging through 50 miles of wind, rain worth it](https://www.abqjournal.com/238425/trudging-through-50-miles-of-wind-rain-worth-it.html):

  - > I crossed the 30-mile mark around five hours into the day.
- [A funny thing happened on the way to the scale: 50 pound mark](http://theincredibleshrinkingfamily.blogspot.com/2008/08/50-pound-mark.html?m=1)

  - Notably, this is about weight *loss*, just for an example of how the expression also can work in the opposite direction in the right context.